# Aligning text with button Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have this html and corresponding CSS code within Shopify

```css
.mobile-menu-icon {
  @include prefix(transform, rotate(0deg), webkit moz ms o);
  @include prefix(transition, 0.5s ease-in-out, webkit moz ms o);
  width: 6.66 * $mobile-icon-line-thickness;
  height: 5 * $mobile-icon-line-thickness;
  display: block;
  display: block;
  margin: (2 * $gutter / 3) auto;
  color: $color-nav;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
```

```html
<a>
      <button id="ToggleMobileMenu" class="mobile-menu-icon medium-up--hide" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="SiteNav">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
       
      <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t }}</span>
      </button></a>
```

The output of this on my website is as so (I have pointed with arrows):

[image]

What I would like to do is to write "MENU" next to this button, where I have drawn the red line for representation purposes. I have tried various options, but I am struggling to align them both correctly to be compatible with different size displays, as well as the button remaining central, as well as the text remaining central to the button.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mobile-menu-icon {
  @include prefix(transform, rotate(0deg), webkit moz ms o);
  @include prefix(transition, 0.5s ease-in-out, webkit moz ms o);
  width: 6.66 * $mobile-icon-line-thickness;
  height: 5 * $mobile-icon-line-thickness;
  display: block;
  display: block;
  margin: (2 * $gutter / 3) auto;
  color: $color-nav;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  }
  .mobile-menu-icon:after{
  content: 'MENU';
  }
```

```html
<a>
      <button id="ToggleMobileMenu" class="mobile-menu-icon medium-up--hide" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="SiteNav">
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
       
      <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.navigation.menu' | t }}</span>
      </button></a>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me.... It just messes up the whole code? Maybe because it is in Shopify and it may be slightly different to standard HTML / CSS? Thanks anyway